# Regarding Kernel $\ker T$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose I have $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ is $T(x,y,z)=x-y-z$.

It is clearly that $T(x,y,z)=0$ iff $x-y-z=0$ so $\ker T$ is non-trivial.

My question is: if I give an example, for instance $(1,1,0)$, so $T(1,1,0)=1-1-0=0$, is that shows that $\ker T \ne$ {$0$} ?

If $\ker T=$ {$0$}, that means that only $(0,0,0) \in \ker T$ ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: @asdq Thanks a lot!